# ReferenceError: afterAll is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, electron

I've been searching about this error on google and already visit almost all of them, but there still no answer how to solve this problem.

I've been trying to delete my node modules and delete package-lock.json then reinstall it. make .env file and add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`. If anyone ever had face this problem or know how to solve it, please share how you face this problem. Thanks in advance...

[image]

and the terminal is not given any error as you can see

[image]

Comment: The error means that mentioned package (jest-specific-snapshot) was added to the build by mistake, while it should be used only in test environment. It's unknown where it got from and how it's related to your project.

Comment: @EstusFlask Im not sure but for information, the project is not build yet, I just run the project for development purpose only.